# Output coupon in the code back end using Craft Commerce

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

I use the plugin Craft Commerce. I can not find how to output the coupon code used by the customer in the back end on the order page.
Anyone would know how to?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I have gone ahead and made the coupon used more visible on the order edit screen. Will be in the next release of Craft Commerce.

In the meantime, if you want the code to show up in the discount description in the backend, add it to the discount description when setting up the discount.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the order detail page in the control panel (i.e. `yourdomain.com/admin/commerce/orders/#####`), then any promotions (sales/discounts) will be listed as a "Discount Adjustment" under the line items for the order.